# Unable to convert Notepad file to .py executable

Tags: windows-10, python

I've made a coding on notepad, saved the file as .py at the end, and I've accidentally opened it as always open these types of files with notepad. I now have 0 clue on how to fix it, I've been googling everywhere on how to fix, with no avail. Help and guidance would be much appreciated. File image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNFB9.png

Comment: Look on the web, e.g. https://www.windowschimp.com/change-what-program-opens-file/

Answer (score 0):

It is still the .py file and does not require you to retype the whole code again. Just right click the file, then open with and use the program you want to open the file with.